# Count exact substring in a string in php

Tags: php

How can I know the exact number of occurences of a substring in a string. For example consider the following string:

```
$string = 'The sun is bright, what a beatiful sunlight';
```

when I search for the word 'sun' I want it to return 1 instead of 2. That happens when I do:

```
$counter = substr_count($string, 'sun');
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$wordCounts = array_count_values(str_word_count($string,1));
$sunCount = (isset($wordCounts['sun'])) ? $wordCounts['sun'] : 0;
```

Case-sensitive... if you want case-insensitive, you'll probably need to use a regular expression using word boundaries

```
$sunCount = preg_match_all('/\bsun\b/i',$string);
```

Comment: `preg_match_all` instead. `preg_match` stops after the first match.

Answer (score 1):

It might be cheating, but you could always search for `' sun '` instead of `'sun'`. :)

```
$counter = substr_count($string, ' sun ');
```

Comment: This is so wrong. How about "sun " and " sun" in the beginning and end of the string?

Comment: @izhak - ha ha. You are right of course. In that case he'd want to use  `preg_match_all` solution in the answer provided by @Mark Baker.

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = substr_count($string, ' sun ');
```

Note however that this wont count words next to a comma or fullstop or at the beginning so it might not help you.